# How to write a function which takes a dynamic key and an item and pushes it to object[key]?

Tags: typescript

I have several objects and types:

```
interface Car {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  year: number;
}

const car: Car = {make: "Tesla", model: "Cybertruck", year: 2023 }

interface Book {
  title: string;
  author: string;
}

const book: Book = {title: "Cosmos", author: "Carl Sagan"}

interface Stuff {
  cars: Car[],
  books: Book[]
}

const stuff: Stuff = {
  cars: [car],
  books: [book]
}
```

I want to define a function that takes two arguments:

- dynamic `key` ("cars" or "books"), and
- an `item` (which will respectively be of ICar or IBook)

and pushes item to `stuff[key]`.

Also when calling the function I want it to infer the type of an item based on the key and autosuggest keys.

What I've tried is this:

```
const addToStuff = ({key, item}: {
  key: keyof Stuff, 
  item: Stuff[typeof key][number] // infers item as Car | Book
}) => stuff[key].push(item)

// .push(item) errors and says 
// Argument of type 'Car | Book' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Car & Book'.
// Type 'Car' is not assignable to type 'Car & Book'.
// Type 'Car' is missing the following properties from type 'Book': title, author
```

here is the [link of the ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGcgWzgGsIAuZAZzClAHMBuPQgewBMIAbC62kR5gE8IGCiACuBAEbQmAXxw4ELENWQJRaDMgC82IqQoAiACoRKnOEYA0rDt2RHUgmVBriExG8mGaATAAMfgDMyAo4oJCwiCgAQiwsxNjMYMBgnORUNPRM+HDiYAAWLFA82fzyisqqYMhSCcQU8Ym62KnpmU4slATd3vlFJcboUJzIAMpwdHAgRuGR0PBIE2DiMDDJ+BpQlBQjANoAutbM9Ym7yM3ERzjh1WrUazAU46vrrbhbGBf728enDR+Z2Ih1uVRUajgbDYJhYryerQAFFhSIJbGkIAQ5BRPshURRUSwNvD1rZmBiCC83jB9mBBAAHCBEvEQQSHfYSaTQUFyACUugAfFknvtUYcAHT08SUQqIim8oA)

Comment: Do you really mean for the function to accept a single parameter which is an object, and then destructure it? Two parameters might be more direct.

Comment: well yeah, that's a good suggestion actually, but it doesn't help with the type inference error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, you need to create higher order function which is context agnostic. Consider this example:

```js
interface Car {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  year: number;
}

const car: Car = { make: "Tesla", model: "Cybertruck", year: 2023 }

interface Book {
  title: string;
  author: string;
}

const book: Book = { title: "Cosmos", author: "Carl Sagan" }

type Stuff = {
  cars: Car[],
  books: Book[]
}

const stuff: Stuff = {
  cars: [car],
  books: [book]
}

const withStuff = <
  Prop extends PropertyKey,
  Value, Data extends Record<Prop, Value[]>
>(data: Data) =>
  <Key extends keyof Data>({ key, item }: {
    key: Key,
    item: Data[Key][number]
  }) => {
    data[key].push(item)
  }

const addToStuff = withStuff(stuff)

addToStuff({ key: 'cars', item: { make: "Tesla", model: "Cybertruck", year: 2023 } }) // ok
addToStuff({ key: 'books', item: { make: "Tesla", model: "Cybertruck", year: 2023 } }) // expected error
```

As you might have noticed, I have added a higher order function to `addToStuff`. Now it is `withStuff` which returns `addToStuff`. You can also use any other data structure where each value is an array, not only `Stuff` data shape.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAdpRN)

You can find more examples with `currying` in [my article](https://catchts.com/currying-components).

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much!

I actually know your blog and have a lot from it, so thank you for that too!

And Слава Україні of course!

Comment: @otchill thank you for your feedback and support!